# How to have a box increase its size based on its content?

Tags: html, css, quirks-mode

Consider a page (full source below) where you have:

- A containing div, styled so its border is visible.
- A contained box, which content can't be made smaller than a certain width. Here we'll use an image for this.

This renders as follows, and as expected the div "contains" the image:

[image: div contains image]

However, if you make the browser window smaller, you get to a point where it is not large enough for the image: part of the image won't be visible, and the browser needs to add a scrollbar. So far so good. However, the div size is still based on the viewport width, and consequently the image gets outside of the div:

[image: div narrower than image]

Instead, I would like to have the div always be "around" the image, and become wider if containing box can't be made narrower. Interestingly, this is exactly what happens in Quirks mode, here as rendered by IE8:

[image: quirks mode]

How can I get, by adding CSS, the exact same result I get in Quirks with IE8, but in standards mode? And for reference, here is the full source of this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Styling */
            div     { background-color: #999 }
            body    { font-family: sans-serif }
            div     { margin: .5em 1em; padding: .5em }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/100"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**:

<s>`Old answer, Truncated`</s>

**HTML**:

<s>`Old answer, Truncated`</s>

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/8Bsgg/)

---

### **EDIT:**

After much tinkering, this is what i could come up with:

**CSS**:

```css
.table {
    display:table;
    background-color: #999;
    width:90%;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    margin: .5em 1em;
    padding: .5em
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="table">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/100"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Accompanying fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/Q4VnF/

Comment: Andres, thank you for looking at this one, but what you suggest doesn't do what I expect: if the browser window is wider than the image, I would like the `div` to use all the full width of the viewport (minus its margin). And if the image is wider than the viewport, I'd like it to extend as necessary. This is what happens if you try the code I have in the question with IE in Quirks mode.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, are you referring to a responsive image that grows and shrinks with the viewport?

Comment: It is simpler than that. Let me try to clarify this. This is what I want: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20110913-good-quirks.mov. Note how when the window comes smaller than the image, the div width becomes constrained by the size of the image? It "stays around" the image. This is what I get in standards mode: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20110913-bad-standards.mov. Note how the browser allows the div to becomes smaller than the image, which I don't want. (And in both cases, if the image is small enough, the div takes the width if the window, which is good.)

Comment: Tried for a good solid hour to trigger the same effect but came up with nothing, quite the bugger.

Comment: This was about the closest i can get it with just css. http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/Q4VnF/show/

Comment: Wow—very nice. Would you mind updating your answer with this, and I will mark it as the correct answer. It is crazy though that we have to resort to the table layout, and we can't just say with CSS that given box should be made larger if its content doesn't fit. Sort of the opposite of what `overflow` does.

Comment: The problem with all the other browsers i found is that they remove the img tag from the html flow thus removing any block-level qualities the images carry...couldn't force it to display as a block-level element though, for some reason only a wrapping div around the image displayed correctly. Updating my answer now.

Comment: A friend looked at this one in parallel, and he came up with a similar solution, except without the row and cell divs, which don't seem to be necessary. See: http://jsfiddle.net/avernet/ccXSC/24/

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for `div { display: table-cell; }`

EDIT: I don't think this can be done with the markup as given. You can get close using `div { display: table; width: 100%; }` but it doesn't like having a margin. If you use two block elements then you can put `{ display: table; width: 100%; }` on the outer element and `{ display: table-cell; }` and the margin, padding and background on the inner element.

Comment: This doesn't work: using `div { display: table-cell; }` the div doesn't take 100% of the width of the viewport, as it does both in Standards and Quirks mode when the image is narrow enough (which is something I want). You get http://i.stack.imgur.com/zE79M.png instead of http://i.stack.imgur.com/B393R.png.

Answer (score -1):

With *display: inline-block* it also works.

Comment: This gets you the same result as `display: table-cell`. See my comment to this other answer for screenshot of how this is different than what you get in Quirks mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368153/how-to-have-a-box-increase-its-size-based-on-its-content/7368218#7368218

Comment: I think that if you don't know the image size or the screen user size it's not posible. You can put a wrapping div with *overflow:auto* but then the scroll bar will appear at the bottom of the image, instead of appearing at the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: Right: I don't know the width of the image, which in my actual scenario isn't really an image, but just some complex dynamic content which may not be made narrower, essentially behaving like an image. But wouldn't it would be frustrating if something that behaved the way I want in Quirks mode wasn't possible at all in Standards mode, even adding CSS rules?